# Fetch Bot Services Teams Channel Health Warnings from Azure Portal via API?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

For an Azure Bot Channel Registration Bot, the Azure Portal in Home->Bot Services->BotName>Channels>Health Column can show any warnings that the platform sees for the Bot.

We have dozens of these Teams Apps with a Bot component, and instead of having to manually review the Warnings from the portal, would like to fetch these logs automatically and analyze them in one place.

Is there an API that will enable fetching of these health warning messages?

If not an API is it possible to have these Warnings delivered via a webhook which we would specify?

Thanks

[image: Azure Bot Service Portal showing Warnings for Teams Channel]

Comment: Currently we don't have any API to get health warning but there is way to add Application Insights and log the warning and issues, I'm checking this will get back to you soon

Comment: Hi - any updates on this @Trinetra-MSFT?

Comment: Currently there is no API available to directly get the health warning, Only way is to implement the logger in your app.